# Laravel 7 - Disable CSRF token for one route of login form

Tags: laravel, csrf, laravel-7

I have set 2 different routes to access the Login page of my Laravel Website.

The first route has @csrf enabled.
For second route I have disabled the CSRF token protection which is used for another purpose (UsED in SAP)
To do this I have added the route '/login' in VerifyCsrfToken.php under protected array.

Due to that thee CSRF token is disabled for both routes.

What is the best way to disable CSRF token for one route only? Please guide

Answer (score 0):

To disable the CSRF protection on some routes:

```
 App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken
```

and edit in this way:

```
  $except = ['/login/HERE_IT_GOES_THE_NAME_OF_THE_METHOD_CALLED_IN_ROUTES' ]
```

where `HERE_IT_GOES_THE_NAME_OF_THE_METHOD_CALLED_IN_ROUTES` is something like:

```
 web.php

  [...]

 Route::get('/login','MyController@NameOfMethod')
```

In this case the exceptions array should look like:

```
         $except = ['/login/NameOfMethod' ]
```

Comment: Well I already did this and it worked fine for me. My question is:  I have added '/login/' in $except variable. I have set 2 routes. Route 1 will access the login form with CSRF token and route 2 will access the login form without CSRF token but I have added the url of login form in $except which disables the CSRF token. So how can route 1 will process the login with CSRF token.

Comment: The routes has the same paths and calling different methods on the same controller?

Comment: Yes. I need to access the login page with 2 different routes. like http://myapp/login and http://myapp/sap. The only difference is that first link uses CSRF protection and 2nd link does not.

Comment: So you should just use `$except = ['/sap/NameOfMethod' ]` or `$except = ['/sap/*' ]`